# Error in Perl: Nested quantifiers in regex

Tags: regex, perl

Im a Perl noob and I have been trying to develop a simple script to capture some values from a regex. So far I have built the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
$/ = '';

my $PM = qr{\b[A-Z][\w-]*\w};
my $de = qr{d[aoe]s?};
my $s = qr{[\n ]};
my $np = qr{$PM (?: $s $PM | $s $de $s $PM )*}x;

my $window_size = 7;
my $window = qr{($np) (?: $s+ (\w+))*};

while(<>){
  while(/($np) (?: $s+ (?: [\w-]+ | ($np))) ** {0..$window_size} /xg){
      print("\$1:  $1 and \$2: $2 \n");
  } 
}
```

However, when I try to run this code, it shows me the following error:

```
Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/((?^ux:(?^u:\b[A-Z][\w-]*\w) (?: (?^u:[\n ]) (?^u:\b[A-Z][\w-]*\w) | (?^u:[\n ]) (?^u:d[aoe]s?) (?^u:[\n ]) (?^u:\b[A-Z][\w-]*\w) )*)) (?: (?^u:[\n ])+ (?: [\w-]+ | ((?^ux:(?^u:\b[A-Z][\w-]*\w) (?: (?^u:[\n ]) (?^u:\b[A-Z][\w-]*\w) | (?^u:[\n ]) (?^u:d[aoe]s?) (?^u:[\n ]) (?^u:\b[A-Z][\w-]*\w) )*)))) ** <-- HERE  {0..7} / at ./main.pl line 22, <> chunk 1.
```

Why is this not working?

EDIT: Im trying to use the `**` operator as the general quantifier, followed by a range. I have read that it is equivalent to {range min, range max} quantifier

Comment: What do you want `**` to mean here?

Comment: What is the string you're trying to match?

Comment: You seem to be confusing Perl and Perl6. `** {0..7}` looks like something Perl6 grammars would do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not matching anything other than the literal string with "**", then you will need to escape it.

```
/($np) (?: $s+ (?: [\w-]+ | ($np))) \*\* {0..$window_size} /
```